# How to delay a timer on an activity launch?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timer

I have implemented a simple timer with CountDownTimer on my game and I need it to start ater a few seconds when the activity is started.

On my main activity's onCreate method, I call this:

playingTime();

Which is as follow

```
public void playingTime() {
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String elapsedTime = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            timer.setText(elapsedTime);
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            timer.setText(R.string.timer_game_over_text);

        }
    }.start();

}
```

The timer start normally but immediatelly as the activity is launched. I would like to set a delay before it get executed or if there is a better way to set timer in games. (Count down timer and nomal timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add delay using Handler like as below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Executed after YOUR_DELAY_IN_MILLIS
    playingTime()
  }
}, YOUR_DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
```

Put the code in your activity onCreate() method

Comment: Thank you. Worked as expected

Answer (score 3):

You can use the handler in **onCreate()** method as shown below and **playingTime** will be called after 1 second

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playingTime();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can set a delay like this :

```
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // call method here
          }
      }, MY_DELAY_IN_MS);
```

Replace MY_DELAY_IN_MS with your own delay

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works as expected